# Informed badge description outdated

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tour, informed-badge

The [Informed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) description still refers to the [About page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) while it was renamed to [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and moved to a new URL after the [unified topbar introduction](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/).

Not sure how the [about-page](/questions/tagged/about-page) tag should change here on meta, but I suggest amending the Informed badge description to reflect the new name and URL of tour page. Using the old name could be confusing for newcomers.

Comment: I'm thinking "***Informed** Took the site tour.*"

Comment: It's still the same about page, the link and URL are just a bit different. Even the old about link that's in the description still works.

Comment: @michaelb958'saSleigh You see the badge’s description before taking the tour when you navigate to http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges – this is the way I got to reading the About page.

Comment: @3ventic Still it can be source of confusion.  The badge is most important for newcomers.  Let’s not confuse them more than necessary.

Comment: @Palec not that I'm against updating it, just a notice.

Comment: The same report arrived as [meta-tag:feature-request] on MSO now: [No more "about" page, time to change the Informed badge description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271975/2157640)